# baseline-prof.txt location for each build variant

Tags: android, performance, android-gradle-plugin, baseline-profile, macrobenchmark

My app has multiple flavor dimensions and so I want to create `baseline-prof.txt` for each variant (e.g. `fooBar`). However, when I place the file in `/app/src/fooBar` it is not picked up during the release build. The only time it is picked up is when placed in `/app/src/main` (as recommended by the docs).

How can this be configured so I can store different `baseline-prof.txt` for each variant?

Answer (score 6):

**Edited 2023-01-16**

Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.0-alpha10 and higher comes with new functionality that allows you to have Baseline Profiles in each build variant.

You can now have the rules in these files:

- `src/main/baseline-prof.txt` (as before)
- `src/main/baselineProfiles/*.txt`
- `src/[variant]/baselineProfiles/*.txt`

You can also have multiple files with generated rules, so for example in addition to the generated rules, you can have couple of manually specified.

There's also option to specify custom folder in build.gradle(.kts) by using (which can be overriden in a buildType or a product flavor)

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    baselineProfiles.srcDirs("[path to folder]")
  }
}
```

---

**Original answer**

Currently this feature is not supported, the profile is accepted only from `src/main/baseline-prof.txt`.

As a workaround, theoretically you could hook a Gradle task into the build tasks, which would copy the desired profile into the required location.

We're aware this can be a blocker, so stay tuned for future updates.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I added a copy task but couldn't figure out where best (i.e. `dependsOn`) to hook it into the build.